# Convert json to a list in underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to use the `_.where` underscore function but I can't seem do get it to work on an array of objects. I have the following json:

```
var Planets = [
        {name:"maths", percComp: "2", preReq: "english"},
        {name:"english", percComp: "20", preReq: "geog"},
        {name:"german", percComp: "20", preReq: "english"},
        {name:"history", percComp: "20", preReq: "german"},
        {name:"irish", percComp: "20", preReq: "geog"},
        {name:"geog", percComp: "20", preReq: ""},        
        {name:"french", percComp: "20", preReq: "spanish"},
        {name:"spanish", percComp: "57", preReq: "french"}          
    ];
```

And then I am using the following code to add each to an array:

```
$(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(Planets))).each(function(){
        var planet = new Class.Planet(this, paper);
        universe.push(planet);            
    });
```

I am trying to use underscore to get items from the list as follows:

```
var planets = _.where(universe, {name: "maths"});
```

But I am getting the following script error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a){return new j(a)} has no method 'where'
```

**EDIT**
You could also use something like

```
var planets = _.filter(Planets, function(p){ return p.name === "maths"});
```

Comment: `$(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(Planets)))` ?????

Comment: Why are you stringifying and then parsing?

Comment: My guess is: to make this example self-contained. The stringification of an in-memory object is just so we have something to copy-paste into a console.

Comment: Haha i changed that just now

Comment: What is `_`, it does not seem to be Underscore? What other scripts do you have included?

Comment: @Bergi It's [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/). Note the tags.

Comment: @millimoose: It does not seem to be the underscore function object, as this would have a `where` method and also its constructor looks different.

Comment: @Bergi What underscore object? [`_.where()`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) is a utility function in that library.

Comment: @millimoose: `Object function (a){return new j(a)} has no method 'where'`

Comment: @millimoose: He's trying to say that maybe the `_` in his code is another library, not underscore, and maybe that's the issue.  The question may be tagged `underscore.js`, but that doesn't mean his code is correct.

Comment: Ahhhh. (Sorry, it took me a while to connect the dots.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_.where` is only available in 1.4.0 http://underscorejs.org/#where

You have to use Varon's suggestion with `_.find`

Or you can simply use JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4mxjb/2/

```
// returns an array with objects where their name 
// property is equal to 'maths'
Planets.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.name === 'maths'
});
```

Comment: Marked this as correct because of the explanation of where not being included in 1.4.0 and how to get around it with js.

Comment: @Juan: Why not use `_.filter`?

Comment: @Bergi For one, `_.filter` only returns the first match, not all of them. Second, why go through a library if the language has that feature standardized?

Comment: @WesleySkeen Just to be accurate, you said `explanation of _.where not being included in 1.4.0` should read `explanation that _.where was introduced in 1.4.0`

Comment: @Juan: I fear you confuse [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) with [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) now. Filter does just what the native filter does, but is cross-browser safe - worth mentioning when he already uses Underscore, but of course native methods are nicer :-)

Comment: @Bergi I have never written a single line of _underscore.js_ Yes, your fears are confirmed, I just went off Varon's answer and didn't even realize you had mentioned `filter` instead of `find`

Answer (score 3):

With underscorejs just get the planet with

```
var planet = _.find(Planets, function(p) {return p.name == 'maths'});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work??? http://jsfiddle.net/4mxjb/ I would suggest changing `planet` to `planets` since it returns an array

Comment: @Bergi, Juan Mendes: You are right. With underscorejs, we could get (more than one) planets with `_.where()`

Comment: @Varon I see...  `_.find` returns just the first match

Comment: Thanks for this alternative but I was looking to return more than one object.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear out the confusion in the older answers:

1. [`_.find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find)

   - input: *comparison function*
   - returns the **first** matching element;
2. [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)

   - input: *comparison function*
   - returns **all** matching elements;
3. [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where)

   - input: *object*
   - returns **all** matching elements;
4. [`_.findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere)

   - input: *object*
   - returns the **first** matching element.

```js
var Planets = [
    {name:"maths", percComp: "2", preReq: "english"},
    {name:"english", percComp: "20", preReq: "geog"},
    {name:"german", percComp: "20", preReq: "english"},
    {name:"history", percComp: "20", preReq: "german"},
    {name:"irish", percComp: "20", preReq: "geog"},
    {name:"geog", percComp: "20", preReq: ""},        
    {name:"french", percComp: "20", preReq: "spanish"},
    {name:"spanish", percComp: "57", preReq: "french"}        
];

console.log('---FIND---\n', // Returns only ONE matching element
  _.find(Planets, function(o){ return o.preReq === 'english'; })
);
console.log('---FILTER---\n', // Returns ALL matching elements
  _.filter(Planets, function(o){ return o.preReq === 'english'; })
);
console.log('---WHERE---\n', // Returns ALL matching elements
  _.where(Planets, {preReq: 'english'})
);
console.log('---FINDWHERE---\n', // Returns only ONE matching element
  _.findWhere(Planets, {preReq: 'english'})
);
```

```html
<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js">
</script>
```